# Erro #VALUE! ao usar operação IF

Tags: microsoft-excel

Tenho esta tabela no Excel e na coluna E tenho a seguinte expressão:`=IF(AND(SEARCH("qwe*";B:B);SEARCH("qaz";C:C));TRUE;FALSE)`

Não percebo porque é que onde deveria aparecer FALSE aparece-me o erro #VALUE!.

Segundo [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/how-to-correct-a-value-error-in-the-if-function-2b87ead5-a61b-4b39-b143-c08a24dbe812?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) pode ser um erro de sintaxe ou a falta de uso de "error-handling formulas".

É possível aparecer FALSE sem usar essas formulas de erro?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode resolver isto com: `=SEERRO(SE(E(LOCALIZAR("qwe*";B:B);LOCALIZAR("qaz";C:C));VERDADEIRO;FALSO);FALSO)`

Que utiliza a função `SEERRO()` OU `IFERROR()` para retornar o valor falso.
Isto ocorre pois ao verificar o que a função search retorna na linha em que o erro ocorre, ela retorna o erro `#VALOR!`. Como na demonstração abaixo.

[image: Demo]

Portanto, para contornar este erro, a função SEERRO é usada.